# How to concatenate command line args for a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, arguments

I'm currently attempting to concatenate my command line arguments with this:

```
for %%a in (%*) do set "subject=%subject% %%a"
```

So for example if I run

```
my.bat subject line here
```

it should set my subject variable to "subject line here", preserving the spaces. However, currently after the run, my subject variable is set to the last word. I get a subject value of " here."

How to concatenate the command line arguments right?

Comment: In case of you want to know why environment variable `subject` does not have the expected string after the __FOR__ loop, open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read all output help pages. There is a `for` example very similar to yours on which is explained why delayed expansion must be used to concatenate the strings correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
SET subject=%*
```

Alternatively enable delayed expansion so that the environment variables don't get substituted during parsing.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (%*) do set subject=!subject! %%a
echo %subject%
```

see [Difference between %variable% and !variable! in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354502/difference-between-variable-and-variable-in-batch-file) for more info.

Comment: No Problem, if this solved your issue then please tick the solution as accepted.