# User input in batch file with default value

Tags: batch-file, user-input

I'm trying to prompt user for input in the batch file with default value *(in case user doesn't enter input)*.

I am trying as given below: 
default values required: 1 to head.

```
set rev1=1
set rev2=HEAD
set /p rev1="start rev: default is %rev1% "
set /p rev2="end rev: default is %rev2% "
```

However prompt shows `start rev: default is` instead of `start rev: default is 1`.

Please help.

Comment: If the posted code is placed between parenthesis (`if`, `for`, ...) then maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could help.

Comment: And put the first double quote left to `rev1` and `rev2` and not after equal sign. This is a common mistake explained hundreds of times in Stack Overflow batch file related topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried c&p your code into a bat file and the output is `start rev: default is 1`. I guess you've posted just a snippet of your code and the this part is inside an **IF or a FOR block**. In this case you should add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your script and access rev1 and rev2 with `!rev1!` and `!rev2!` instead of `%rev1%` and `%rev2%`.

Comment: Yes, it was in an IF block, and your solution worked. thank you!