# Batch file loosing variables in FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am struggling with this one for some time now. Tried WITH and WITHOUT EnableDelayedExpansion, but no joy. Simply, the variable %MYFILENAME% is empty right after it's set in a loop:

```
::echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo -- BACKUP DATABASES --
set MYPATH=D:\SQL_BACKUP
set MYDBASES=db1 db2 db3 db4

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set MYDATE=%%c%%a%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set MYTIME=%%a-%%b)
set MYDATE=%MYDATE:.=-%

for %%q in (%MYDBASES%) do (
    echo DB %%q processing 
    set MYFILENAME=%MYPATH%\%%q_%MYDATE%_%MYTIME%.bak
    set SERVERNAME=.
    echo %MYFILENAME%
    echo sqlcmd -B -E -S %SERVERNAME% -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%%q] TO DISK = N'%MYFILENAME%' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'%%q backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        echo OK
    ) else if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
        echo failed!
    )
)

echo.
set MYDATE=
set MYTIME=
set BACKUPFILENAME=
set MYPATH=
set MYDBASES=
set MYFILENAME=
```

What I get is lost %MYFILENAME% imediatelly:

```
echo DB db1 processing
 set MYFILENAME=db1_11-11-2016_0-54.bak
 set SERVERNAME=.
 echo <<<----------HERE MISSING MYFILENAME ----------<<<
 echo sqlcmd -B -E -S . -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [zdvrhnika] TO DISK = N''
WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'zdvrhnika backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT
"
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**
After changing MYFILENAME and SERVERNAME variables to some simple texts, I found out, that they do not change at all! MYFILENAME is always empty, and SERVERNAME is always ".", regardless of what I set them to?! And regardless of whether I use SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion or not.
It's not script fault, but some environment stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch - Set variables in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706234/batch-set-variables-in-for-loop)

Comment: Also related: [Variable setting exhibits unexpected behavior when set inside for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702040/variable-setting-exhibits-unexpected-behavior-when-set-inside-for-loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` **and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` ** or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Comment: A third way is to use a pseudo call and double the percent signs `call echo %%var%%` or `call set Var=%%OtherVar%%`

Comment: Magoo, excellent! Works like a charm (replacing %variable% with !variable! inside block statements)! Thank you very much!