# Batch Programming - comparing string

Tags: session, batch-file

I want to perform an action for selected group of people for this I am tried writing a batch command which work perfectly in performing action for all the group of people so I added a if condition which will pick only the people begin with that string name. Please find below the code. But it is somehow now working.

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

query session >session.txt

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2," %%i in (session.txt) DO (
SET _prefix=%i:~0,6% 
IF %_prefix%==myuser (
    logoff %%i
    )
)

del session.txt

EndLocal


Output of query session : 

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           myuser01                 1  Active
```

There can be multiple session like myuser02,myuser03 and so on

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could help

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('Qwinsta^|find /i "myuser"') DO (
      logoff %%b
)
```

May be this will be easier?

Comment: Why include token 1? Also, FINDSTR would be more precise: `for /f "tokens=2" %%U in ('qwinsta^|findstr /bri "...................myuser"') do logoff %%U`

Comment: Thanks dbenham and npocmaka