# difference goto :eof and :eof

Tags: batch-file, scripting, eof, goto

I'm new to batch scripting. Can you tell me what's the difference
between `goto :eof` and `:eof`?  And why do some people write `!ERRORLEVEL!` with exclamation marks?

Sorry for this noob questions but I couldn't find an answer yet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:eof` is a reference to the End Of File, a virtual label (does not need to be defined) where to jump to end the current batch context.

`goto` is a command used to jump (interrupt the current flow and continue in another named point) to a label

`goto :eof` is a jump to the end of the file

`errorlevel` is the name of a variable that holds the exit code of the last executed command (if it sets it)

If you want to retrieve the value inside this variable you use `%errorlevel%`.

But, as in batch files variables are replaced with its value at parse time (please, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476)), sometimes it is necessary to indicate to the parser that this should not be done and delayed expansion syntax is used, so variable read operations are not replaced until the moment the command is executed. The syntax to indicate it to the parser is `!errorlevel!` having delayed expansion enabled (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command).

Comment: Thank you very much, thats now clear to me! And thanks for the link.