# Batch for loop with multiple commands and enabledelayedexpansion for a beginner

Tags: batch-file

I need some batch-noob-treatment.

I'm trying to rename all the files in a folder and I'm slowly getting there, but although I got the step right with some google help, I would like to know what I'm doing.

Here is my code until now:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set a="dir /b"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (' %a% ') DO (
set str=%%i
set str=!str:~1!
echo !str!
)
```

Anything else I put inside the for loop brings out strange results. I know the `enabledelayedexpansion` and `!` are somehow connected and make this work, but how is the inside of a for loop different from the normal commands in batch, so that special syntax is needed?

What goes wrong if I put in code like that:

```
@ECHO OFF

set a="dir /b"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (' %a% ') DO (
set i=%i:~1%
echo %%i
)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could help

Comment: Your link looks like it could work for me. I'll need some time to read it all and figure it out. Sorry I didn't see the question, but it's title is different. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set i=%i:~1%` is wrong as there is a *gigantic* difference between `for` loop  **control variables** (e.g. `%i`) versus **environment variables** (e.g. `%i%` or `%str%`) and appropriate manipulation with them:

- (`%~i`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command line arguments and `FOR` parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%variable:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

**Further resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)