# Concatenation in windows shell not working

Tags: windows, cmd

apparently this batch file should return the concatenation of the input files given as arguments, but it is not working:

```
set files=
for %%i in (%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8) do (
    echo %%i
    set files=%files% %%i
)

echo "the file list is %files%"
```

when invoked with:

```
mybatchfile.bat example1.txt example2.txt
```

the expected result should be:

```
example1.txt
example2.txt
the file list is example1.txt example2.txt
```

but in the final line only has "example2.txt". Any idea???

Comment: Delayed expansion. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) should help

Comment: Ok, thanks!!! Now it's working

Comment: do you know `%*`? (will give you the complete list of parameters. Just try `echo %*`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable delayed variable expansion (note the expansion `!files!` in the following code):

```
set files=
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8) do (
    echo %%i
    set files=!files! %%i
)
endlocal & set files=%files%
echo "the file list is %files%"
```