# Why is SET inside of an IF ignored on the first run?

Tags: batch-file

The following code:

```
@IF [1]==[1] (
  @SET test="This is a test"
  echo --%test%--
)
```

When run twice, outputs the following:

```
----
--"This is a test"--
```

Why does this first one not have any value in the variable?

Comment: Your problem is variable expansion. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could help

Comment: You're both right. I had trouble searching for this one, sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The `()` is actually a line continuation, so the entire `if` "line" is parsed (and variables substituted) before the `set` command every executes.  You need to use `enabledelayedexpansion`:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@if [1]==[1] (
  @set test="This is a test"
  echo --!test!--
)
```