# My CMD batch script is not working(0 was unexpected at this time.)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

as the title says, my batch script is not working, all i know that this error happens after "**REM BUCKS**", also i saw the text "**0 was unexpected at this time.**" before quitting, can you guys see what is the problem?and maybe provide a solution?i need this code for my game.

This script is a scoring script, i simulate it by adding the "**SETs**"

Under the "**REM SCORE**" will set the earn to 0 if the earn variable is a negative.

I cannot give you the full script beacuse its so huge

here is the code:

```
SETLOCAL
set stage=add
set r=10
set dif=3
set timer=30
set w=2
set cash=6
REM BUCKS
if %stage%==cha (
set st=10
REM SCORE
call :calculator %r%*10*%dif%*%st%-%w%*%timer%
timeout 5 > NUL
set earn=%val%
if %earn% LSS 0 set earn=0
set /a cash=%cash% + %val%
goto :EOF
)
if %stage%==0 goto :EOF
if %stage%==add set st=3
if %stage%==sub set st=4
if %stage%==mul set st=5
call :calculator %r%*10*%dif%*%st%-(%timer%*%w%)
set earn=%val%
if %earn% LSS 0 (
set earn=0
)
set /a cash=%cash% + %val%
pause
exit
goto :EOF
:calculator
>"%temp%\VBS.vbs" echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") : Wscript.echo (%*)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\VBS.vbs"') do set "val=%%a"
del "%temp%\VBS.vbs"
goto :EOF
```

thx for reading

Comment: Variable expansion. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) int the `IF` block and I'm not sure if your vbscript will not do what you intend. Here's improved version of your script that uses the u[ber-geeky batch/vbscript hybrid technique](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33963#p33963)  which will reduce your IO operations and the script will be faster:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
set stage=add
set r=10
set dif=3
set timer=30
set w=2
set cash=6
REM BUCKS

if %stage%==cha (
    set st=10
    REM SCORE
    call :calculator "%r%*10*%dif%*%st%-%w%*%timer%"
    timeout 5 > NUL
    set earn=!val!
    if !earn! LSS 0 set earn=0
    set /a cash=!cash! + !val!
    goto :EOF
)
if %stage%==0 goto :EOF
if %stage%==add set st=3
if %stage%==sub set st=4
if %stage%==mul set st=5
call :calculator "%r%*10*%dif%*%st%-(%timer%*%w%)"
set earn=%val%
if %earn% LSS 0 (
    set earn=0
)
set /a cash=%cash% + %val%
echo %cash%
for /f "tokens=2" %%# in ("%cmdcmdline%") do if /i "%%#" equ "/c" pause
exit /b %errorlevel%

:calculator
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /noLogo "%~f0?.WSF"  //job:calc "%~1"') do set "val=%%a"

exit /b %errorlevel%

   <job id="calc">
      <script language="VBScript">
        WScript.Echo(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
      </script>
  </job>
```

Comment: Hello, im confused, i thought you need to type "**CMD /V:ON**" before using "**!**" as a variable delimiter

Comment: @Daxter - in batch file you can use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` . `CMD /V:ON` is needed when you want to use delayed expansion directly in command prompt.

Comment: what does "**directly**" means?

Comment: to use it in the console but not using a script file.