# windows batch script loop through file

Tags: shell, batch-file

How do I write a batch script that loops through each line in a text file and stores the line in a variable in the loop?

For example I have:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\pmandayam\git\devops\UserRegistrationServices\scripts\file.txt) do (
    set var1=%%A
    echo %var1%
)
```

For some reason, the output keeps printing `echo is OFF.` multiple times, instead of the actual line

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Either use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) or `call echo %%var1%%`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set statements don't appear to work in my batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177307/set-statements-dont-appear-to-work-in-my-batch-file)

Comment: It works with `!var1!` but what is 'variable expansion'?

Comment: "variable expansion" means replacement of the variable by its value; the standard method is using `%var1%`; with this syntax, the variable is expanded immediately when the command line or parenthesised block of code is parsed (immediate expansion); when using delayed expansion and `!var1!` is stated, the variable is expanded when the affected code portion is executed; to enable delayed expansion in a batch file, put `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`; otherwise, the `!var1!` syntax has no special effect...