# Unable to display variable using %

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I was going over an example batch file that was able to display a variable outside of a loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
:: count to 5 storing the results in a variable
set _tst=0
FOR /l %%G in (1,1,5) Do (echo [!_tst!] & set /a _tst+=1)
echo Total = %_tst%
```

It's able to echo `%_tst%` because it's declared at the top before the loop.

I tried it with a batch file that I'm currently using:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set drive=R:
set counter=0

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%c IN ('dir %USERPROFILE%\Backup /B') DO (set /A counter+=1)

if %counter% GTR 0 (
    echo Total # of folders: %counter%  
) else (
    echo No folders to move
)
```

It works, but, when I try to check if a drive is available before executing the loop, I have the use !counter! to access the variable, like so:

If I don't, it just says `"Please press any key to continue."` because of the pause.

```
@echo off
cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set drive=R:
set counter=0

if exist %drive% (

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%c IN ('dir %USERPROFILE%\Backup /B') DO (set /A counter+=1)

    if !counter! GTR 0 (
        echo You have !counter! folder(s)
    ) else (
        echo No folders to move
    )
)
pause
exit /b
```

Why is it that when I have the if statement checking if my drive is available I have to use `!counter!`?

Comment: If you change a variable inside a block of code (`if exist` in your sample) you need delayed expansion to retrieve the changed value while inside the same block of code

Comment: @MCND - The if exist is sort of blocking the delayed expansion from being seen? Where should I put the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion?

Comment: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` does not mean that any variable read operation is delayed until code execution. It means that you can use the `!var!` syntax to indicate that this read operation must be delayed. `%var%` read operations will be replaced at parse time with or without `enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could help.

Comment: @MCND - Many thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the `)` in the text `file(s)` - this closes the inner `if !counter! GTR 0` block. Then it sees another `)` which closes the outer `if exist %drive%` block.

To fix this, escape the `)` in the `echo`:

```
if exist %drive% (

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%c IN ('dir %USERPROFILE%\Backup /B') DO (set /A counter+=1)

    if !counter! GTR 0 (
        echo You have !counter! folder^(s^)
    ) else (
        echo No folders to move
    )
)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Corrected. I'm still a little confused, how would I access the counter variable outside the for loop? should I use !counter! or %counter%

Comment: A block `( ... )` counts as a single line to the parser so all %variable% are expanded with their values before the block runs. The !variable! delays the expansion until run time. So inside the block, use !variable!

Comment: Just to be clear if I wanted to access my counter outside my for loop, I would use !counter!, correct?

Comment: That's right - you'd use !counter!. I tried the above with %counter% and it returns 0.

Comment: Been trying for hours trying to understand why it returned 0. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a Backup folder so I used Documents instead which I know has files in it and %counter% returned 0 inside the if exist block.