# How to run a batch file to test the server twice if it fails the first test

Tags: batch-file

Below is my code i am using right now, it is working but the second if command is reporting the down when there is no down, please help me and point out where i did mistake,

```
echo on
setlocal
set itemail= "mail id"
C:
cd\
cd batch
Call utltest.cmd >status.txt
ServerTester.exe -services acgenpszrwbklquf  >>status.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
wmailto mailid -s"UP -  Health Monitoring." -tstatus.txt"
) else (
c:
cd\
cd batch
Call utltest.cmd >status.txt
ServerTester.exe -services acgenpszrwbklquf  >>status.txt
)
if %errorlevel%==0 (
wmailto mailid -s"UP -  Health Monitoring." -tstatus.txt"
) else (wmailto %itemail% -s"DOWN - WebServices Health Monitoring." -tstatus.txt
)

:eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is

```
check server
if errorlevel == 0 (
   send mail
) else (
   check server
)

if errorlevel == 0
```

and here, in the second errorlevel check there is an ambiguity: you don't know if the errorlevel value that you are checking has been generated by the `send mail` or the `check server`

Simplify, don't duplicate code. Just loop over the test checking for sucess. If we reach the limit of checks inform of the error

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "itemail=mail id"

    pushd "c:\batch" || goto :eof

    set "tries=2"
    for /l %%a in (1 1 %tries%) do (
        >status.txt (
            call utltest.cmd
            ServerTester.exe -services acgenpszrwbklquf
        )

        echo The ServerTester returned errorlevel : !errorlevel!

        if not errorlevel 1 (
            wmailto "%itemail%" -s"UP -  Health Monitoring." -tstatus.txt
            goto :eof
        )
        if %%a equ %tries% (
            wmailto "%itemail%" -s"DOWN - WebServices Health Monitoring." -tstatus.txt
        )
    )
```

To avoid problems with delayed expansion, the code uses `if errorlevel n`. This way we are not reading the value in the variable (`%errorlevel%`), but using the available `if` syntax to check against the current `errorlevel`.

Comment: This very nice and working good, but one thing is we have to consider the error code 1 as well, because our tester will return different value when there is a fail, so i have to change one line logic ( if not errorlevel 1), i have tested with differet combinations( if errorlevel == 0, if errorlevel equ 0, if %%a equ 0 ) but no luck!!!, can you please guide me to edit this logic

Comment: @T.Anand, `if errorlevel n` is evaluated to true for any errorlevel value *greater than or equal* to `n`. So, `if not errorlevel 1` means *"if the errorlevel is not at least 1"* that is, *"if the errorlevel is 0 or less"*. If you want to check for different values, use `if errorlevel n` from greater to lower values.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! but generally if not means " if that is not true" right and also my concern is here we havent used any compare-op like(EQU, NTQ, GTQ,GTR) then how the script will assume like "if the errorlevel is 0 or less" for "if not errorlevel 1" this is my confusion.

Comment: @T.Anand as said, `if errorlevel 1` does not check if the error level is 1, it checks if the error level is at least 1 (it can be 27 and the condition will be true). So, the negation of `>=1` is `<1`, that is, `<=0`

Comment: it displays errorlevel =0 for all type of failures!!

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) to understand *why* you are failing to retrieve the value in `errorlevel`. Also, I've included in the code a way to solve it (changes in 2nd and 15th lines)

Comment: I want to understand what the exact error so that i can troubleshoot the issue that is the reason i want to display the %errorlevel%

Comment: Yes because of delayedexpansion  i am failing to retrieve the value thanks for making me understand as i am beginner but very much interested to learn the batchscripting please help me, now i have tested the code with enabledelayedexpansion but no luck, i have used %errorlevel% and also !errorlevel! below is the result..... SOAP : <-- FAIL -->0.2184042 secs 
The ServerTester returned errorlevel : 0 
The ServerTester returned errorlevel : 0

Comment: i think you had changed the line2 and line11 now, it worked for me !!!. is this is the way to solve ? can i use it

Comment: @T.Anand ,for me it is not 11 but 15 (blank or not a line is a line), but yes. When inside a block if you want to retrieve the value from a variable changed inside the same block, delayed expansion is the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: @T.Anand, Did you read [the previous link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476)? `!errorlevel!` is the same that `%errorlevel%` In both cases we are refering to the same variable, **but** the `!var!` syntax changes **when** (in what moment) the batch parser retrieves the value from the variable.

Comment: this script was working fine, recently i found that if all the service failed it is not sending the mail alert either UP or DOWN,