# How can I use a loop variable in for cycle .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem with .bat

```
@echo off
    set NAMEFILE=version

rem counting commas
set "f=%VERSION%"
set "vz=,"
set /a "z=0,n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /r /c:"\%vz%" "%f%"') do set "s=%%a"& call :#
<+ (for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ('more') do set /a "z+=%%b")& del+

set /a z =%z% + 1

rem cycle with problem
rem tokens=%%a* - part of the code that contains the problem
for /l %%a in (1,1,%z%) do for /f "tokens=%%a* delims=," %%i in (%NAMEFILE%) do @echo %%i>File_%%a.vers


:#
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 2>nul
  for %%a in ("!s:~%n%,1!") do (

   if "%%~a"=="%vz%" set /a z+=1
   if not "%%~a"=="" set /a n+=1& goto #
  )
 endlocal
exit /b
```

I don't know what to do with "tokens=%%a". It doesn't see variable %%a, maybe because of "%" symbols. I think it must be escaped or something like this. If u can help, please help.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you expect and where it fails, it seems that there is much unrelated code. You should try to reduce your code to show a minimal example of your problem and describe what you get and what you expect

Comment: I have a problem only with following string : `for /l %%a in (1,1,%z%) do for /f "tokens=%%a* delims=," %%i in (%NAMEFILE%) do @echo %%i>File_%%a.vers`. Specifically in this place: `"tokens=%%a* delims=,"`. I need to use "`%%a`" variable in `"tokens=%%a*"`, but I can't do it. It doesn't put this variable in that place. It ignores that. I assume that variable can be escaped somehow, but' I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use neither delayed expansion nor FOR-parameter expansion in the options part of a `FOR` command (The same is true for `IF`).
It's caused by the way the batch parser handles them.

But as said only parameter and delayed expansions fail, percent expansion still works.

But in your sample you can't use it *inline*, you need to build a helper function.

```
...
for /l %%a in (1,1,%z%) do call :helper_func %%a
...


:helper_func
for /f "tokens=%1* delims=," %%i in (%NAMEFILE%) do @echo %%i>File_%%a.vers
```

It looks strange that in the helper function, you still can use `%%a` in `echo %%i>File_%%a`.
This is the effect that all currently used FOR-parameters are visible inside all FOR-loops (even when they appear to be unrelated).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have tried this code 
`@echo off 

set /a z=2
set /a c=0
for /l %%a in (1,1,%z%) do (
 set /a c=%c%+1
 echo %c%
)`

And I have gotten following output: 
"0
0"
. Is there a way to increment the variable %c% inside the loop. Why has not it changed?

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov That question is unrelated to your primary question, but have a look at [Why are my set commands resulting in nothing getting stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14347038/463115)